# How to remove empty lines at the end of a file using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to remove all empty lines that are ONLY located at the end of the file using `awk`

I was able to successfully find a way to delete all of the empty lines at the top only with the following command:

```
awk '/^$/ && a!=1 {a=0} !/^$/ {a=1} a==1 {print}' file.txt
```

However, I didn't know how to reverse it so I could remove the bottom lines instead. I know I could just use the command above and pipe it with `tac`, but I prefer a direct approach using `awk` command only (if possible).

To clarify, a line is considered "empty" if it is "visually empty", i.e. contains at most spaces and/or tabs.

Comment: Is a line that only contains spaces (e.g. blanks and/or tabs) considered "empty" or not?

Comment: @EdMorton It doesn't matter as long as it is empty (regardless if it contains spaces and/or tabs). The goal here is just to make sure the last printed line contains info/data. My priority is that it should be done using `awk`

Comment: For future questions - `as long as it is empty`is an ambiguous statement because some people consider a line of blanks to be empty (as you apparently do) while others consider only a line that has no contents to be empty. So if/when you find yourself referring to any data as "empty" in future be sure to state what you mean by that. Most of the answer you have so far (e.g. all those that test `^$`) will fail given an "empty" input line that contains blanks since we're all making different assumptions about what "empty" means.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh yeah.. I get your point. You are right. I should have phrased my question better. Thank you for your clarification, brother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Awk

Since Awk reads the file sequentially, from the first to the last line, without external help (e.g. Tac) it can only figure whether a block of empty lines is at the end of the file when it actually reaches the end of the file.

What you can do is keep a variable with the empty lines (i.e., only newline characters, the default record separator `RS`) and print those empty lines whenever you reach a non-empty line:

```
awk '/^$/{n=n RS}; /./{printf "%s",n; n=""; print}' file
```

> I don't understand why there is a difference between `print n` and `printf n`.

[`print` appends the output record separator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_10) (`ORS`, by default a newline) to the expression to be printed. Thus you would get an extra newline if you tried it. You could also write it with a single output statement as in

```
awk '/^$/{n=n RS}; /./{printf "%s%s%s",n,$0,RS; n=""}' file
```

---

##### [Ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) or [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)

To print the output (just as Awk did), choose either of

```
printf '%s\n' 'a' '' '.' '?.?+1,$d' ',p' 'Q'  | ed -s file
printf '%s\n' 'a' '' '.' '?.?+1,$d' '%p' 'q!' | ex -s file
```

To directly apply the changes to the file, choose either of

```
printf '%s\n' 'a' '' '.' '?.?+1,$d' 'w' 'q'   | ed -s file
printf '%s\n' 'a' '' '.' '?.?+1,$d' 'x'       | ex -s file
```

[To understand what's going on.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596696)

##### [Command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)

Shells strip trailing newline characters in command substitution.

```
printf '%s\n' "$(cat file)"
```

Mind that some shells will not handle large files and error with "argument list too long".

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552205).

Comment: Note that in the general case `printf var` is wrong as the first argument of `printf` is the format. So it's better to use `printf "%s", var`. Using `printf n` here should be harmless though as the variable only contains newline characters so should be guaranteed not to contain `%` characters (note that for the `printf` utility, backslash characters are also a problem in addition to `%`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, very true. Although that's no concern here as you said, it's good to stand by the good practice so I've edited the answer.

Comment: The ‘nifty trick’ is likely to be inefficient for all but very small files, and fail completely for large ones.  (The exact limit, and the behaviour for files exceeding it, will depend upon the shell you're using.)

Comment: Thanks @gidds, I have added a warning about that limit. I tried it for ¬(very small files), namely for a 10MB file with 116600 lines, and it executed in decimals of a second, while Awk was five times faster (so indeed slower, but not that bad).

Comment: I think with ex you could do something like `printf '%s\n' \$ ?.?+,\$d %p q\!` (where I’ve eschewed the append and used the idiomatic % instead of ,)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You can only skip appending the empty line if you can guarantee the file has a trailing empty line. This is similar to the approach contained in the answer I linked to. Thanks for catching the `,p`, that one is only for Ed.

Answer (score 6):

```bsh
awk 'length == 0 { ++n; next } { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print ""; n = 0 }; 1' file
```

or shortened, as suggested in comments,

```bsh
awk 'length == 0 { ++n; next } { while (n) { print ""; --n } }; 1'
```

This keeps track of runs of empty lines in the counter `n`.

Whenever an empty line is seen (`length == 0`), the counter is incremented but nothing is output.

When a non-empty line is seen, the appropriate number of empty lines is first output before the current line.  The counter `n` is also reset.

This avoids outputting empty lines from the end of the file.

---

Using standard `sed`:

```bsh
sed -n -e :again -e N -e '/[^\n]/!b again' -e p file
```

This introduces an explicit loop that adds lines to the buffer until there is something other than just newlines in it.  At that point, the buffer is output.  If the input file ends while reading with `N`, the data in the buffer (which will be only newlines) will not be output.

Annotated code (the initial `#n` turns off the default output, just like using `-n` would do):

```
#n

# Label to branch to later.
:again

# Append next line of input to buffer
# with a delimiting newline.
N

# Branch (jump) to :again if there's
# only newlines in the buffer.
/[^\n]/!b again

# Output buffer.
p
```

Comment: Don't forget that [^\n] is nonportable , GNU-specufic regex.

Comment: +1 for the awk approach. It can further be simplified via down counting while loop.

Comment: @guest_7 [From POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): "The escape sequence '\n' shall match a <newline> embedded in the pattern space. A literal <newline> shall not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function.".  What is GNU specific is to _insert_ a literal newline using `\n` with the `s///` command.  I have tested my code with `sed` on OpenBSD and Plan 9.

Answer (score 6):

This 1-pass approach will work whether the input is coming from a pipe or a file but has to store each block of empty lines in memory (which probably won't really be an issue unless you have billions of contiguous empty lines in your input):

```
awk 'NF{print s $0; s=""; next} {s=s ORS}' file
```

This 2-pass approach won't work if the input is a pipe, but will if the input is a file as you said in the question and uses almost no memory:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (NF) n=NR; next} FNR>n{exit} 1' file file
```

The above assumes that a line that contains only spaces is considered "empty". If that's wrong then change `NF` to `/./`.

Comment: I like your approach. I understood most parts, but I still need your help for more clarification, (if you don't mind of course). I am really confused on what `s=s ORS` means. Can you explain what that line means? Would there be a difference if I used `RS` instead? Thank you very much for your time and help. Thanks to you, I learned that `NF` ignores everything including multiple spaces and tabs while `!/^$/` doesn't. I also learned from you about `next` and how I can use it. :D

Comment: `s = s ORS` is just collecting a string of spaces (empty lines). which will get printed when the next non-empty line is hit, or discarded if those empty lines were at the end of the file. ORS is the **Output** Record Separator, RS is the input Record Separator. We're building a string of lines to **Output** so, while In your case it seems like RS and ORS are probably the same thing (`\n`) so functionally it doesn't matter which you use, technically `ORS` is correct so ensure your "empty" lines have the same terminator (`ORS`) as your non-empty lines being output by `print` (i.e. also `ORS`).

Comment: You'd see the difference between using `RS` and `ORS` when populating `s` if you wanted your output lines to end in `|\n` or something. If you're using `ORS` when populating `s` then all you need to do is set `-v ORS='|\n'` on the command line and everything will work, but if you're using `RS` to populate `s` then you have a problem and some coding to do. Try it to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` and  its range operator `,`

```
awk '
!NF,NF{
  t = ($0 = t $0) ORS
  if (!NF) next
  t=""
}1' file
```

We  accumulate the empty lines + one nonempty line in t. If a nonempty is seen we flush tHe buffer **t** and restart the process of accumulation.

---

With all-POSIX constructs, we can do it using the sed utility as shown:

```
sed -e '
  /^\n*$/!b
  $d;N;s/./&&/;D
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
co=`awk '!/^$/{x=NR}END{print x}' filename`
co=$(($co+1))
j="$co,$"
sed -i "${j}d" filename
```

Tested and worked fine

Comment: As always - http://shellcheck.net.....

Comment: And, as always,  please don’t use `awk` and `sed` *in combination* to do something that either one of them can do alone.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666541)

> What you can do is keep a variable with the empty lines (i.e., only newline characters, the default record separator RS) and print those empty lines whenever you reach a non-empty line

but using `sed`

```
sed -n -e '/^$/H' -e '/^$/!{x;/^$/!{s/\n//;p;z};x;p}'
```